# interpretation of a group action

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be an abelian group. Let $\beta$, $\alpha :G\rightarrow Aut(A)$ be two homomorphisms. It is well known that if there
exist $\sigma \in Aut(A)$, $\rho \in Aut(G)$ such that $(\beta \circ
\rho )(g)=\sigma \circ \alpha (g)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$, then the semidirect products $A\rtimes _{\alpha
}G$ and $A\rtimes_{\beta}G$ are isomorphic.

However, in one stage of a proof, I get that there
exist $\sigma \in Aut(A)$, $\rho \in $ $Aut(G)$ such that $(\alpha \circ
\rho )(g)=\sigma \circ \alpha (g)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$. Is there
any interpretation of this formula in group theory? why this might be an interesting property?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but note that $\rho$ induces an automorphism $\hat{\rho}$ of $\alpha(G)$, and your equation says that $\hat{\rho}$ is the restriction of an inner automorphism of $Aut(A)$ to $\alpha(G)$.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you see as interpretation, but rather something to note which I cannot write in a comment: You condition can be rephrased as the fact that the following diagram commutes:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G @>{\rho}>> G\\
@VV{\alpha}V @VV{\alpha}V \\
\text{Aut}(A) @>{\text{conj}(\sigma)}>> \text{Aut}(A)
\end{CD}$$

Here $\text{conj}: A \rightarrow \text{Aut}(A)$ is the group action of $A$ on itself via conjugation.